# Photos are not displayed in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I have this error, when open website

**GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/categories/portable.jpg 404 (Not Found)
categories:73**

This is link of the code in the browser https://imgur.com/a/VwXavqd

In my .env file i wrote:

**APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000**

**FILESYSTEM_DISK=public**

But it doesn't help.

Comment: Did you create the storage link?

Comment: @brombeer yes, i did

Comment: where are your files located?

Comment: @Garry resources  > images > categories

Comment: oh. u have files in the resources folder. so "/storage/category....." not gonna work.
if you want to access it that way you have to put files in storage -> app -> public -> categories.

Comment: @Garry I've changed, but still doesn't work
https://imgur.com/pcY5Pwj

Comment: <img src="/storage/images/categories/portable.jpg" />

Comment: @Garry sorry, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first thing

Delete **storage folder** from public

And run this again

```
Php artisan storage:link
```

Then go to your `config/filesystems.php` and check your disk configuration

Also sometimes it can be caching  issues
So Try **running**

```
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put file `portable.jpg` in the `storage>app>public>images>categories` folder use  `<img src="/storage/images/categories/portable.jpg" />`

Or if you put that in the `storage>app>public>categories`
use `<img src="/storage/categories/portable.jpg" />`

And also make sure you used command `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: https://imgur.com/qKh0RE2
and the same error

Comment: can you show where `portable.jpg` file exists?

Comment: https://imgur.com/TsTrzl8

Comment: ok, so you used `/storage/categories/portable.jpg` in your img tag and you are sure. so you are used command `php artisan storage:link` ?

Comment: can you show public folder content

Comment: yes, i did this step "php artisan storage:link"
public folder https://imgur.com/n2NSIWB

Comment: @KostyaKhmylov your problem is solved?

Comment: yes, i pointed this out